# Where to find my Yahoo Application id?

Tags: php, api, oauth, yahoo, yahoo-api

I'm trying to add a yahoo login to a php website using [Yahoo! Social SDK - PHP5](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php5) which seems the official and most updated PHP SDK

I created an app from https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/ and followed the instructions provided in examples.

So at this early point I have to define Client ID, Client Secret, Application ID and the Callback URL to set the YahooOAuthApplication class.

```
$CONSUMER_KEY = '##';
$CONSUMER_SECRET = '##';
$APPLICATION_ID = '##';
$CALLBACK_URL = '##';
$oauthapp = new YahooOAuthApplication($CONSUMER_KEY, $CONSUMER_SECRET, $APPLICATION_ID, $CALLBACK_URL);
```

I visited https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/ and chose the application I previously created but I couldn't find the Application ID.

I also tried the last part of the url when in application but that didn't work either.

Comment: I also contacted yahoo support, but i got no response.

Answer (score 11):

Go to https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/

Clic on your app

See URL, you'll get something like this :

https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/TKI2Mw7f/

The key **TKI2Mw7f** at the end is your appID (This is an example)

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid whether Yahoo provides Application ID for latest APIs versions, please check their documentation.